# Google Chrome links now appear as crossed out not underlined why?

Tags: google-chrome, appearance

Since Sunday when I use Google Chrome links now appear as crossed out not underlined why? They still function but I have no clue how this has happened or how to change it back. Is not problem when I use Firefox.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you installed any extension that day?

Comment: Are you loading any custom stylesheets?

Comment: @kalaracey - Since Chrome auto-updates with zero user interaction, I'm not sure it's really fair to ask if someone updated chrome on a given day.  The rest of the questions are good, though.

Comment: @Iszi that's true.  I was thinking of firefox. But I think I figured out the problem -- see my answer. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is caused by an add-on called "SeoQuake"
When the SeoQuake's dropdown menu is opened, and the "`Highlight NoFollow`" option is toggled on (i.e., there is a checkmark next to it) all of the links are displayed as "strikethrough" instead of "underline". Deselecting this option, then refreshing / restarting Chrome should do the trick.